# need to fetch all the students who have not paid for the current month

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

Students table :

```
id   studentname   admissionno
3    test3               3
2    test2               2
1    test                1
```

2nd table is fee :

```
id   studentid  created
1       3       2015-06-06 22:55:34
2       2       2015-05-07 13:32:48
3       1       2015-06-07 17:47:46
```

I need to fetch the students who haven't paid for the current month,
I'm performing the following query:

```
SELECT studentname FROM students 
    WHERE studentname != (select students.studentname from students
    JOIN submit_fee
    ON (students.id=submit_fee.studentid)
    WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(submit_fee.created)) ;
```

and I'm getting error:

> '#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Can you tell me what the correct query is to fetch all the students who haven't paid for the current month?

Comment: to start with, use NOT IN instead of !=   , also you can improve the query!!

Comment: thx amit..NOT IN is working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use not in, please try query below :

```
SELECT s.*
FROM students s
WHERE s.id NOT IN ( SELECT sf.studentid FROM studentfees sf WHERE month(sf.created) = EXTRACT(month FROM (NOW())) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `not exists` or a `left join` for this:

```
select s.*
from students s
where not exists (select 1
                  from studentfees sf
                  where s.id = sf.studentid and
                        sf.created >= date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate) - 1) and
                        sf.created < date_add(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate) - 1), 1 month)
                 )
```

Note the careful construction of the date arithmetic.  All the functions are on `curdate()` rather than on `created`.  This allows MySQL to use an index for the `where` clause, if one is appropriate.  One error in your query is the use of `MONTH()` without using `YEAR()`.  In general, the two would normally be used together, unless you really want to combine months from different years.

Also, note that paying or not paying for the current month may not really answer the question.  What if a student paid for the current month but missed the previous month's payment?